# What is the equivalent of GNU's --wrap linker flag in OS X linker?

Tags: c, linker, clang, gnu, ld

I'm trying to port a C program compiled with GNU toolchain to OS X but its default `ld` program does not support the `--wrap` flag, which is present in GNU's `ld`.
This is from the man page of GNU's `ld`:

```
--wrap symbol
    Use a wrapper function for symbol.  Any undefined reference to sym-
    bol will be resolved to "__wrap_symbol".  Any  undefined  reference
    to "__real_symbol" will be resolved to symbol.

    This  can  be used to provide a wrapper for a system function.  The
    wrapper function should be called "__wrap_symbol".  If it wishes to
    call the system function, it should call "__real_symbol".

    Here is a trivial example:

            void *
            __wrap_malloc (size_t c)
            {
              printf ("malloc called with %zu\n", c);
              return __real_malloc (c);
            }

    If you link other code with this file using --wrap malloc, then all
    calls to "malloc" will call the function  "__wrap_malloc"  instead.
    The  call  to "__real_malloc" in "__wrap_malloc" will call the real
    "malloc" function.

    You may wish to provide a "__real_malloc" function as well, so that
    links  without the --wrap option will succeed.  If you do this, you
    should not put the definition of "__real_malloc" in the  same  file
    as  "__wrap_malloc";  if you do, the assembler may resolve the call
    before the linker has a chance to wrap it to "malloc".
```

Is there a portable way of achieving this?

Comment: You mean `ld64` not `clang`.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the title

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue but never found an equivalent. Following workarounds can help, depending on what you exactly intend to achieve.

1) [Wrapping symbols during linking on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441587/wrapping-symbols-during-linking-on-os-x)

2) https://discussions.apple.com/thread/617779?start=0&tstart=0